# Prevent display from sleeping

Tags: display, sleep-wake

I'm trying to use an auxiliary LCD as a light-pad/bed/table by loading up a 1080p white .PNG in preview and setting fullscreen ON.

The problem is after several (20?) minutes of inactivity I get the Apple screensaver kicking in, and then have to enter my password.

How to prevent this?

Nothing in System Prefs -> Energy Saver works.

http://osxdaily.com/2011/03/21/temporarily-prevent-a-mac-from-sleeping/ suggests `pmset noidle` but that's also fails.

Comment: Does System Preferences -> Desktop and Screensaver -> Screensaver not work?

Comment: @JMY1000, thanks, this is the answer! And my bad for being really blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen Saver is under System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Screen Saver, not System Preferences > Energy Saver. Simply navigate to this preference pane, then in the bottom left corner, select the Start after: menu and choose Never.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the "sleep corner" mentioned in Tetsujin's answer, there is also a small app out there called [Caffeine](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipgoDI0_XMAhWiy4MKHYmxBcUQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fcaffeine%2Fid411246225%3Fmt%3D12&usg=AFQjCNG3ASSwgMLZm2ucpqyoIZbTUIaKJA) which you can use to prevent the machine (and thus display as well) from sleeping. Note that it will even stop a laptop from sleeping when the lid is shut, so be sure to disable it. There are also alternatives like [Amphetamine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12) and [Owly](https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/owly-sleep-prevention/id882812218?mt=12) that seem to do the same thing, but I've only use Caffeine. All of them hit the same underlying OSX setting, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Try System Prefs > Desktop & Screen Saver > Hot Corners.

I have mine set like this... just shove the cursor to the top left of the main screen & no more nodding off...

[image]